# list concatenation by linking instead of copying over

Tags: python

A list can be extended with another by `copying` the second over:

```
fst, snd = [1], [2]
fst.extend(snd) # copying the second
print(fst, snd) # [1, 2], [2]
snd[0] = 3
print(fst, snd) # [1, 2], [3]
```

Wondering how to `link` instead of `copy` the second over:

```
print(fst, snd) # [1, 2], [2] after linking the second
snd[0] = 3
print(fst, snd) # [1, 3], [3]
```

Comment: There's no way to do this with vanilla lists, integers are immutable.

Comment: There isn't a way to do that in with the standard libraries, but you could write your own implementation :) But most importantly, if this isn't just a learning example, do you need that functionality? This leads to quite unexpected behaviour which might confuse others trying to understand what's happening, or even you when you come back to it after a month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Borrowing the idea on holding the references of all the `linked` lists in the underlying composite list from `@Alain T.`:

```
 class List:                                                                                                           
     def __init__(self, *els):                                                                                         
         self._lst = [list(els)]                                                                                       

     def link(self, *lsts):                                                                                            
         for lst in lsts:                                                                                              
             if isinstance(lst, list):                                                                                 
                 self._lst.append(lst)                                                                                 
             elif isinstance(lst, List):                                                                               
                 self._lst += lst._lst                                                                                 
             else:                                                                                                     
                 raise TypeError("Wrong type.")                                                                        

     def __iadd__(self, lst):                                                                                          
         self.link(lst)                                                                                                
         return self                                                                                                   

     def __iter__(self):                                                                                               
         return (el for lst in self._lst for el in lst)                                                                

     def __len__(self):                                                                                                
         return sum(map(len, self._lst))                                                                               

     def __getitem__(self, idx):                                                                                       
         if idx < 0:                                                                                                   
             idx += len(self)                                                                                          
         for lst in self._lst:                                                                                         
             size = len(lst)                                                                                           
             if 0 <= idx < size:                                                                                       
                 return lst[idx]                                                                                       
             idx -= size                                                                                               
         raise IndexError("Wrong index.")                                                                              


 import unittest                                                                                                       


 class TestList(unittest.TestCase):                                                                                    
     def setUp(self):                                                                                                  
         fst, snd, trd, foth, fith = [0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7], [8, 9]                                            
         self.els = fst + snd + trd + foth + fith                                                                                                                                                           
         self.lst = List(*fst)                                                                                         
         self.lst.link([], snd, List(), List(*trd))                                                                    
         self.lst += []                                                                                                
         self.lst += foth                                                                                              
         self.lst += List()                                                                                            
         self.lst += fith                                                                                              

     def test_init_link_iadd_iter(self):                                                                               
         self.assertEqual(list(self.lst), self.els)                                                                    

     def test_len_getitem(self):                                                                                       
         size = len(self.lst)                                                                                          
         for i, ids in enumerate([range(size), range(-size, 0)]):                                                      
             with self.subTest(i=i):                                                                                   
                 self.assertEqual([self.lst[idx] for idx in ids], self.els)                                            


 if __name__ == "__main__":                                                                                            
     unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create an additional list to hold references to the lists you want to concatenate.  This will allow you to manipulate the lists independently while maintaining access to the concatenation of all your lists.  Accessing the concatenated result would work a little differently however:

```
fst, snd = [1], [3]
linked   = [fst,snd]

# define an iterator to access concatenated lists 
iLinked  = lambda:(e for lst in linked for e in lst) 

for e in iLinked(): print(e)  
# 1
# 3

fst.append(2)
snd.append(4)

for e in iLinked(): print(e)  
# 1
# 2
# 3
# 4

thrd = [5,6]
linked.append(thrd)

for e in iLinked(): print(e)  
# 1
# 2
# 3
# 4
# 5
# 6
```

Answer (score -1):

if you are saying to bring the contents of a list to another without copy, this might be your go:

```
fst = fst+snd
print(fst, snd) #prints [1,2], [2]
```